# Disable GPU on certain applications

Tags: python, pytorch

I was trying to train some neural network on an Nvidia GPU, but it seems the desktop environment (KDE) is occupying the GPU:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Apr 22 09:04:16 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.39                 Driver Version: 375.39                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1295MiB /  2002MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1139    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             681MiB |
|    0      1591    G   kwin_x11                                        50MiB |
|    0      1594    G   /usr/bin/krunner                                13MiB |
|    0      1596    G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                           126MiB |
|    0      2267    G   ...el-token=FF7F1AB0E04D51461A7E5E08B2463625   136MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the python code I was running:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms


transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))

# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
print(' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))


from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()
net.cuda()


import torch.optim as optim
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data

        # wrap them in Variable
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs.cuda()), Variable(labels.cuda())

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.data[0]
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 64, in <module>
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 147, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device_id))
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 118, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 124, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 147, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device_id))
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/pytorch/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 65, in _cuda
    return new_type(self.size()).copy_(self, async)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (46) : all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.cu:66
  car   cat  bird   dog
```

How can disable those kde related processes from using the GPU, and let them use Intel graphics instead?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and would probably be better off asked somewhere else, like askubuntu.com

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking maybe this will involve some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you don't have enough GPU memory for training. There are some solution:

1. **Reduce batch size**: Only a batch is load into GPU at a time. Small batch size would occupy less GPU memory. (try to reduce batch size to 1 to see if it work ?). Look, you have more that 500 MiB of GPU memory left and you have batch size of 4. If you cannot run the model with only 1 batch, then there is high chance that trying to free 681MiB of /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg won't help you.
2. **Run the very simple example code on GPU** (should not be computer vision problem so it does not take too much GPU memory). This step confirm that you install CUDA and Pytorch correctly and your GPU should work.
3. **Turn off GUI and run in terminal only mode** (because you do not need GUI, just a terminal is enough for run python code), it saves 600 MB of GPU memory. It is much easier that trying to move GUI into others GPU. Try searching for keyword: "how to turn of GUI in ubuntu "